# C function parameter as a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int *i) {
    (*i) = (*i) + 1;
}

int main() {
    int pskills[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int i, *ptr ;
    ptr = pskills;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        fun(ptr++);
        printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After I compile the code, the results are:

```
20
30
40
50
```

However, based on my understanding, the output should be:

```
11
21
31
41
```

I am confused. Can anybody help me understand this?

Comment: Note: the parenthesis are only required if you are operating on the pointer itself where operator precedence requires it. E.g., the following are all equivalent in `fun`, `*i = *i + 1;` or `*i += 1;` or `(*i)++;` Where `++` has higher precedence than `*` requiring the `(..)` to force the dereference first.

Comment: We start to answer the questions on such an elementary level. Maybe someone should add another forum for people who just started learning programming. Otherwise many of us just waste time reading it. In this case the Author did not even try to understand how 5 lines of code work. It is easier to ask the question on the forum, than to think and figure it himself.

Answer (score 3):

In the first pass, you pass a pointer to `pskills[0]` to `fun` (incrementing `10` to `11`), but you increment `ptr` before the `printf`, so you print `pskills[1]` (`20`).

In short, you incremented `ptr` too soon. You want

```
fun(ptr);
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
++ptr;
```

or

```
fun(ptr);
printf("%d\n", *(ptr++));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change these lines from:

```
fun(ptr++);
printf ("%d\n", *ptr);
```

To:

```
fun(ptr);
printf ("%d\n", *ptr++);
```

What you see right now is an effect of `ptr++`, the post increment operation. The value associated with the pointer is updated, but then the increment occurs before you can see the change printed.

---

I should also mention that your array size is 5, but your loop is running for 4 iterations only... but if that's how it is, then fine. However, an even better approach with your loop, as suggested by @DavidC.Rankin in the comments is to not hardcode any of your values as much as possible.

For example, to get the length of the array after you have first declared it, you can use

```
int n = sizeof pskills / sizeof *pskills;
```

And then use `n` to step through your loop:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: You can also eliminate magic numbers altogether with `int n = sizeof pskills / sizeof *pskills; for (i = 0; i < n; i++) ...` and given C-operator precedence `*ptr++` is fine. The parens are only required, e.g. if you increment `i` in `fun`, e.g. `(*i)++;`

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand your a code bit.

```
fun(ptr++); // Post increment first assigns value then increments.
```

Therefore `*i` will receive the address of `pskills[0]` which has value `10` and it increments it to `11` as you expected.

Now comes the part where you are confused.

```
printf ("%d\n", *(ptr) );
```

Before the execution of above line, `ptr` now started pointing to the `pskilss[1]` because of post increment operator you used on `ptr`. Remember I said in post increment the assignment is done before increment.So after call return the increment is done. This is why it printed `20` instead of `11`. Likewise for all other values.

Now if you need to print `11 21 31 41` there can be many ways to do so.

Well, I am discussing one here without changing much of your code.
simply replace your printf statement with the below statement and you are good to go.

```
printf ("%d\n", *(ptr-1) ) ;
```

Now, I added that little `-1` just to explain you the reason why you were not getting the expected output and i.e. just because of increment operator. `-1` here cancels out the effect of increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the pointer before you print the content `fun(ptr++);`.
You want to increase the content, then print, then increase the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int *i)
{
    (*i) = (*i) + 1;
}
int main(void)
{
    int pskills[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int i, *ptr ;
    ptr = pskills;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <4 ; i++ )
    {
        fun(ptr);                // first increase content, without increasing the pointer
        printf ("%d\n", *ptr ) ; // then print content, before increasing
        ptr++;                   // THEN increase the pointer
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11
21
31
41
```

Bingo! As desired.
(I notice that you expect only 4 values, which matches your loop. The array has 5 entries, but you obviously are aware of that.)